# Query with strftime Function Produces Empty Results in DuckDB Connection to SQLite

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, duckdb

I use a duckdb connection to sqlite, and when I write this query:

```
con.sql("""
SELECT 
    strftime(CAST(created_at AS DATETIME), '%Y') as year,
    COUNT(*) AS review_count,
    p.title
FROM reviews r
JOIN podcasts p ON r.podcast_id = p.podcast_id
WHERE year != 'None'
GROUP BY year, p.title
ORDER BY year;
""")
```

It results in a totally empty results table. But if I run the query with just SELECT and the function alone, it works properly and gives me the whole list of values. I don't understand why it's not working in this query

Comment: What's the contents of the `created_at` column? And remove the cast; sqlite doesn't have a "datetime" type. See https://sqlite.org/datatype3.html#date_and_time_datatype

Comment: the created_at is a column containing dates in this format: 2018-04-24T12:05:16-07:00.

You just made me doubt something. I used to use pandas.read_sql_query method to get the queries done and into a pd.dataframe, but maybe this method doesn't use SQLite dialect but instead pandas'own SQL dialect. Could this be the issue?

Comment: @spool Your date format syntax is screwy. Use this instead: `strftime('%Y', created_at)`. See: [Date And Time Functions](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html).